# Moving rows preserving original ID but allowing auto increment in destination table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a cron job that moves rows from one table to another if the original row is over 2 weeks old. I'm using Laravel.

Here is the schedule call function:
**kernel.php**

```
$schedule->call(function() {

    try {

        DB::transaction(function () {

            $to_move = DB::INSERT("INSERT INTO archived_articles
                               SELECT * FROM articles 
                               WHERE progress = ?
                               AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), publish_date) > ?"
                               , ['2', '14']);

            if ($to_move) {
                $deleted = DB::DELETE("DELETE FROM articles
                               WHERE progress = ?
                               AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), publish_date) > ?"
                               , ['2', '14']);

                if ($deleted) {
                    Logging::logCronSuccess("{$deleted} articles archived");
                } else {
                    Logging::logCronSuccess("No articles archived");
                }
            }

        });

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Logging::logCronError($e, 'Cron error archiving articles');
    }

})->dailyAt('00:05');
```

I used CURDATE rather than NOW - in case the (albeit very unlikely) situation occurred where the first query didn't find anything, then when the delete query ran, the time lapsed since the first query meant it DID find articles, and they would be deleted but not moved.

I mirrored the **archived_articles** table on the **articles** table, but on the insert, the auto increment id column is currently being populated with the original **article.id**. I'd like to preserve this in it's own column, so that there is never a risk of a collision - so I've added an '**article_id**' column to the **archived_articles** table.

Is there a way of using the INSERT INTO SELECT FROM statement - ***without having to list the column names*** but preserving the auto increment in the archive table, and inserting the article.id in the article_id column?

The reason for not listing the columns is in case we make a change to the articles table - which is not unlikely - we then have to remember to also make the change to the archive table, or that column will be missed an no error raised.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server here?

Comment: sorry MySQL (removed extraneous tag)

Comment: shouldn't your delete query delete records from the articles table instead of the archived_articles table?

Comment: yes - corrected, wasn't formatting properly so manually wrote it in. thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you add a new auto_incrementing column 'newID' to the archive table, you can insert your data like so:

```
$to_move = DB::INSERT("INSERT INTO archived_articles
                           SELECT NULL as newID, * FROM articles 
                           WHERE progress = ?
                           AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), publish_date) > ?"
                           , ['2', '14']);
```

Your original id should not be a UNIQUE column in the archive table, just a index, or you would still have the duplicate issue.

Comment: presumably 'id' in the archive table then becomes the original article id, and newId is the auto_inc?

Comment: OK. So out of interest - do you see a reason why there might be a clash. Because another table - attachments, used an article_id to link it to an article. Don't really want to have to archive those too, just use the article_id in the archive table when displaying attachments for archived articles. If articles are deleted, the auto_increment id doesn't then become available at any point, does it?

Comment: Let's say you have ID 1,2,4,5 in your table. The database will not want to insert (re-use) ID 3, but always use the next new ID (6). You can insert a row with ID 3  manually, so yes there is a risk of clashing, but only if YOU insert clashing rows. But another question: what is the reason for archiving? If you add a column 'is_archived' (BOOL) to the initial table, you can just keep archived rows in the table, but ignore them in your queries.

Comment: that's a valid point regarding the is_archived column - probably a better idea. Guess I was thinking querying articles (non-archived) which happens a lot - whereas archived ones less so, would be faster with all old ones removed - but at what point would this become noticeable?